# Can I use MySQL with ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have started using `MVC3` recently,

I want to know, Can I use `MySQL` with `ASP.NET MVC3`?

How can I link the database with it? Suggest me how can I do it?

Comment: you know, google could have answered faster than it took asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried connecting with a database by adding a new item which is a data template, this will load the database you made.  You needed a connectionstring, a method to open/close the connection and a method to execute the sqlcommand.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC is a web development framework. It has nothing to do with your Data Access methodology or won't bother about what your back end data source is. You can create applications which queries data from any data source like SQL server / MySQL/ Oracle /XML file etc..

**So the answer is YES**. You can use ASP.NET MVC with MySQL. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL) is a good tutorial how to connect to MySQL from your C# code.

Comment: +1, done this on several projects, works great.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has an ADO.NET provider (which has nothing to do with MVC)
http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Devart is another company offering a provider called dotConnect.
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/